# Debian Stretch VLC has no GUI

Tags: debian, gui, vlc

I've been trying to install VLC for Debian Stretch and can get the command line to work fine, however I can't get the GUI to open.

I've Googled this a bunch and came across multiple different examples of a similar issue, but so far none of them have been able to help.

The furthest I have gotten so far is I have compiled VLC 3.0.4 from Source I downloaded from VLC. This now works perfectly from the command line, but there are no GUI elements on the video playback (like play and pause buttons) and I can't open VLC from the applications menu, only the command line.

The output of VLC -vvv gives no errors (as far as I can tell) so I'm a little stuck for what to try next.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try installing the Debian `vlc` package? Make sure you install `vlc`, and not `vlc-nox`, to get the GUI.

Comment: Hi, yeah I've tried installing vlc straight from the debian repo, but that got me the same result

Comment: What happens if you press F11 when VLC is running?

Comment: As far as I can see F11 does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try to install package phonon-backend-vlc.

Comment: Only if the OP is using KDE... I run VLC on Debian 9 with a GUI without `phonon-backend-vlc`.

Comment: Sorry should have said, I'm using Gnome 3.22?